# How do I classify when I have only positive use case of data in machine learning?

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, classification

My question is Can we classify something when we have a set of data which is related to only positive use case of a data?

I know this is confusing, let me put it this way, say..

In a classifier, we have to train it with A and B where A is the positive data set and B is the negative data set. But here I have only positive data set of my action/use case and have no way to retrieve negative data set.

Can I use machine learning to classify whether the coming data is positive or not?

If yes, which classifier can be used to get my job done?

A ruby based solution is preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer - No. If you dont have negative use case data, how will the algorithm decide if the incoming data is negative, because it doesn't have any basis of comparison

Comment: Let me give you a use case, we have data of nuclear plant operation. We never have data of a nuclear collapse. It's possible to classify based on that? Did some research and found that there's a way called one class classification. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well that is a case of Outlier detection. You can use clustering based techniques and detect if any incoming value belongs to that cluster or not. SVM can also be used.

Comment: Could you collect unlabelled data anyway, where positive and negative examples occurs?

Answer (score 0):

May be [One Class Learning using Support Vector Machines](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/ManevitzY01.pdf) will help you. But these type of ML algorithms has a lot of limitation when you apply.